# Spring - Thymeleaf Date type

Tags: spring, date, thymeleaf

I'm new at Spring and thymeleaf,so sorry for the silly question.

I have a form that must filter some data based on a date that the user choose.
I have this class:

```
public class RequestFilterEntity {
  private Date requestedAt;
  private Date dateScheduled;
  ...
 }
```

I have this endpoint in the controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/requests", method = POST)
    public String filterRequests(RequestFilterEntity requestFilter, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("requestFilter", new RequestFilterEntity());

    return "admin/reporting/filter_requests";
}
```

and this View:

```
 <form method = "post" th:object="${requestFilter}" th:action="@{|/admin/reporting/requests|}">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="requested">Requested at </label>
      <input id="requested" type="date" class="form-control" th:field="*{requestedAt}"/>
    </div>
```

I want that the object requestFilter that the Controller pass to the View will have the Date requestedAt set with the date chosen by the user (note that I am using input type="date")

Does it make sense? I have an error into the view. Can someone help me out? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Could you please include which error do you have?

Comment: The error is HTTP Status 400 "the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect". There is some problem with the view. I don't even know how to debug it. I'm sure that the problem is with the date type because if I get rid of it the View just load fine

Comment: What browser are you using type=date is not supported in most

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems.

1. You are passing an empty object from your controller and expecting it to show up in your views.

`model.addAttribute("requestFilter", new RequestFilterEntity());`

2. You are not formatting your date object. Please add this `initbinder` to your controller

`InitBinder` for custom date editor

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

Comment: I pass an empty object because I want the View to set my object variable (it worked for other int and String variables, but it's not working for the date type)

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you explain further about this comment?